# Regular Expression function for maximum 15 characters

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for a reference number to be entered by a user that takes a maximum of 15 characters (numbers and letters only). 
How best do I implement this?
Here is what I have tried to date.

```
private static final String MY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = ("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
```

Comment: add `{0,15}` after character class. Remove `^` from character class. REGEX: `"[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,15}"`

Comment: `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15}$"` (also remove `^` from character class which is used for negation.

Comment: It is part of a form page, a user can enter a maximum of 15 characters and at least 1. Why am I being voted down?

Comment: Then use `{1,15}`, this means one to fifteen characters of previous class.

Comment: OK, when I type characters in now it only allows me to type 7 maximum. Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: For clarity, which language are you using? I gave you a PHP answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15}$
```

`^`: Start of the string, followed by...

`[a-zA-Z0-9]`: ...any alphanumeric character...

`{1,15}`: ...1 to 15 times, followed by...

`$`: ...the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

**In PHP**

```
/\A(?>[A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}?){1}?\z/u
```

Processing UTF-8? Better add the /u modifier. Be careful about metering the greediness of regular expression quantifiers and the "one timeness" and "capture state" of regular expressions generally.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, can you show me where they () & "" are placed?

Comment: I thought you only wanted letters and numbers? Why do you need a `&` ? I have use () to simply demarcate that the pattern I've described should only be looked for one time.   `(?>  .......){1}?` makes the pattern you place inside "one time" and "non-capturing and non-greedy". `[A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}?` looks for 1- 15 letters or numbers, "non-greedy."

Comment: @Tushar No warning necessary if this is for PHP.

Comment: I think this is Java or C#